# Adding event listeners to all interactive elements (e.g. inputs, selects) vs handling one by one

Tags: javascript, performance, addeventlistener

I wonder which of the methods is better in terms of performance: adding an event listener and one single handler function for all interactive elements at once, or to add an event listener plus handler function for specific needs only?

Recently I decided to compact the code of a project by adding a listener for all the inputs on a page, and I noticed a glitch. On the other hand, if I add separate listeners and handlers as I add code the response time increases proportionally and becomes more and more difficult to maintain.

Is there a good practice for this dilemma? Any guidance is welcome because I really do not know how to approach the issue.

Comment: Perhaps consider a different approach: for every possible event that you want to listen for, add a *single* delegated listener to the `window`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I get the point, thank you. I'm not so familiar with window events, it seems I have to evolve. :)